# Request() with scandinavian letters

Tags: python-3.x, ascii

When I am trying to request following URL that has the special letter ä:

```
req = Request(https://www.booli.se/slutpriser/frosunda/874692/?objectType=Lägenhet&page=1)
```

I get the following error when i run it:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe4' in
>   position 45: ordinal not in range(128)

Is there a special encode I should import in order to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

That's not valid code, and not a terribly clear use of the Requests class (assuming you're using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)).

Perhaps this will do what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import requests
req = requests.get("https://www.booli.se/slutpriser/frosunda/874692/?objectType=Lägenhet&page=1")
print (req.text)
```